# Error logging with MERGE query in Oracle 11

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-tuning

I am using Oracle 11 and I have millions of records in my table. I am using a `MERGE` statement to update records from source table to target table.

At any moment while updating these millions of records, how can I log errors per record?

For example: I have successfully updated 400 records, but while updating 401st record, I am getting some error, so in this case how can I log something like

> 401st record and its failure cause

So that from these millions of records I can identify for which records the query has failed.

Comment: Hi RockingDev!  If any of the answers are helpful mark them as such.  If you found any of these to match as an appropriate answer set them as the answer in order to allow the Stackoverflow community to see that an answer was found.  Of all the questions you have asked which the community have answered it does not appear that a single answer was marked with a followup.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get to pick your own error, but you can use the error_logging_clause. See Oracle documenation at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606.

You will first need to create an error log table with DBMS_ERRLOG. At the end of your merge statement you need to tack on

```
LOG ERRORS INTO <<errorLogTableName>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can log the errors in the same table or a table of your choosing.  In the example provided below I created a table called `tst_merge` and populated it with 7 rows of data into 2 columns `column1` and `data_to_update` to keep it simple.  To maintain this simplicity I created the table with a 3rd column to store any Oracle Errors but this column can be in ANY table - preferably in an table that is used to track these errors.

This answer also assumes that you are at least somewhat comfortable with PL/SQL.  I am unable to think of a way for this to be possible without PL/SQL using my example.

> **SETUP** the table and insert Data Code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE "TST_MERGE"
  (
    "COLUMN1" NUMBER,
    "DATA_TO_UPDATE" CHAR(9 BYTE),
    "DB_ERROR" VARCHAR2(200)
  )
;

INSERT INTO tst_merge (column1, data_to_update) VALUES (1001, 'dataInRow');
INSERT INTO tst_merge (column1, data_to_update) VALUES (7001, 'dataInRow');
INSERT INTO tst_merge (column1, data_to_update) VALUES (3001, 'dataInRow');
INSERT INTO tst_merge (column1, data_to_update) VALUES (4001, 'dataInRow');
INSERT INTO tst_merge (column1, data_to_update) VALUES (5001, 'dataInRow');
INSERT INTO tst_merge (column1, data_to_update) VALUES (6001, 'dataInRow');
INSERT INTO tst_merge (column1, data_to_update) VALUES (2001, 'dataInRow');
```

> The **CODE** to do what you are requesting is below.  PL/SQL.

```
DECLARE
  /* Store Error Code and Message so we can log these values into a table */ 
  sql_error_num   NUMBER          :=  0;
  sql_error_msg   VARCHAR2(100)   :=  '';

  CURSOR cur_MergeData IS
    SELECT column1, data_to_update
      /* The below line builds a character n times as the new string to update into the data_to_update field */
      /* Here this is simply going to force the error ORA-12899 'Value Too Large for Column'                 */
      , rpad('L', (to_number(SUBSTR(column1, 1, 1)) * 2), 'L') AS new_string
    FROM tst_merge
    ;

  TYPE t_MergeData IS TABLE OF cur_MergeData%ROWTYPE; /* Type declared based on Cursor     */
  c_MergeData  t_MergeData  :=  t_MergeData();        /* Collection declared based on Type */


BEGIN

  OPEN cur_MergeData;
    FETCH cur_MergeData BULK COLLECT INTO c_MergeData; /* Fill Collection with data from Cursor */
  CLOSE cur_MergeData;

  IF c_MergeData.COUNT > 0 THEN
    FOR r IN c_MergeData.FIRST .. c_MergeData.LAST
    LOOP

      BEGIN
          /* Output row data just for troubleshooting */
          dbms_output.put_line(c_MergeData(r).column1 ||' '|| c_MergeData(r).new_string );

          /* Merge Code */
          MERGE INTO tst_merge tm USING
          (
          SELECT column1, data_to_update
          FROM /* When Merging into the same table the MERGE INSERT ONLY works if a record is returned. */
               /* The dual table forces a record with columns values of NULL to be returned if NO MATCH is found. */
            (SELECT 1 AS fake FROM dual) d
            LEFT JOIN tst_merge t ON t.column1 = c_MergeData(r).column1
          ) m ON (m.column1 = tm.column1)

          WHEN MATCHED THEN       

          UPDATE SET data_to_update = c_MergeData(r).new_string
          WHERE column1 = c_MergeData(r).column1

          WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

          INSERT (column1, data_to_update)
          VALUES (c_MergeData(r).column1, c_MergeData(r).new_string)
          ;

      EXCEPTION       
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
          sql_error_num :=  SQLCODE;
          sql_error_msg :=  SQLERRM;

          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error '||TO_CHAR(sql_error_num)||': '||sql_error_msg);

          UPDATE tst_merge SET db_error = ('Error '||TO_CHAR(sql_error_num)||': '||sql_error_msg)
          WHERE column1 = c_MergeData(r).column1;

      END;          

    END LOOP;
  END IF;

END
;
```

> Gif below to see it in action

[image]